# ubuntu windows doesn't refresh correctly in case of dual screen

Tags: graphics, 16.10, desktop-environments

in ubuntu 16-10 `4.8.0-41-generic` window leave traces of old positions but no hangs only in case of extended screen.
happens in both cases of enabling intel-integrated, or ARM drivers

example

[image]